# CSS Cross Browser Timed Animations

Tags: css, animation, visibility

I have some things that need to be Hidden for a few seconds and then appear. This code works perfectly in Chrome but does not work anywhere else. Can anyone tell me how to make it work in Firefox/IE ?

```css
.titlebox .md a[href*="#nm"] {
    -webkit-animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.25s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    animation-duration: 1.25s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.25s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
.titlebox .md a[href*="#dm"] {
    -webkit-animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.25s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    animation-duration: 1.25s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.25s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    opacity: 1
}
.side .md h4:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.25s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    animation-duration: 1.25s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-name: hidemeforabit;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.25s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hidemeforabit {
    from {
        width: 0 !important;
        height: 0 !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        right: -100000px !important;
        z-index: -1 !important;
        display: none !important;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes hidemeforabit {
    from {
        width: 0 !important;
        height: 0 !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        right: -100000px !important;
        z-index: -1 !important;
        display: none !important;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes hidemeforabit {
    from {
        width: 0 !important;
        height: 0 !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        right: -100000px !important;
        z-index: -1 !important;
        display: none !important;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate the `-webkit-animation` properties, remove `-webkit-` and place them after the prefixed property. [Most browers support the native CSS property, including the latest Chrome stable](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) -- [Here is an example snippet](http://jsbin.com/pupoxo/1/edit?css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the properties are applied at the end of the animation, removing the element.

To simply hide on load and then show an element, use `opacity`:

- The animation can be simplified and written in the [shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Syntax)
- The default iteration count is `1` so this can be omitted
- Specify an unprefixed property as well as the `-webkit-` [most browers support the native property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

### Example

```css
div {
  -webkit-animation: hidemeforabit 3s;
  animation: hidemeforabit 3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hidemeforabit {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes hidemeforabit {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Here I am!</div>
```

Comment: I need to be hidden for a few seconds, then be visible. wont doing it this way make it visible then hide it?

Comment: Misspoke - if you remove *all your current animation CSS properties* and use **exactly what I have in my example** (using your selectors), it will work.

Comment: ok. I have it "sort of" working now. it does infact make it see through for a moment, however this method is not yet "perfect". some of my other CSS makes the div position:absolute and moves it close to the top of the page. in chrome it hides the div completely until after the animation timer is over, but in Firefox the div is visible but slightly clear and then it moves itself into the correct position after the animation timer is over. which looks very bad

Comment: @AverageJoe - Can you pop some HTML in your question along with the CSS that you have now that replicates this issue?

Comment: its for my reddit. notice the "night mode" on the right side. works exactly how i want it to in Chrome. not so much everywhere else.  http://www.reddit.com/r/blackdesertonline/